# How to run "Activity A" class under "Activity B" class by onListItemClick

Tags: java, android

I have two classes "XMLParser" and "MainActivity". How to run "XMLParser" class under MainActivity class by onListItemClick. Here, I have two questions. (1) How can I pass String packageName from MainActivity to  parseXML() method. (2) Why this toast message didn't appear. I don't know what are the errors exactly. Please suggest me some advices. Thank you for your answers.

```
public class XMlParser extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    parseXML();
    }

    public void parseXML(){
    String input = packageName + ".xml";
    .........................
    .........................
    .........................
    String result = something;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Second Class "MainActivity"

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
        }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        String packageName = app.packageName;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMLResult.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }
```

Comment: By Looking at your code, I have doubt for, `XMlParser` is an Activity(As i didn't see any setContentView()) or You want a normal java class which parse xml file? In that case you don't need `XMlParser` as Activity just create simple java class and pass package name in constructor.

Comment: Your XMLParser class seems like a utility class and I don't think you should extend it to an Activity. Activity classes in Android, provides user interaction capabilities. You can create a plain Java class for XML parser, and create a constructor in it, which takes a string as an argument. Then call your XMLParser constructor in onListItemClick

Comment: And also you are calling the Toast code in the XML parser, ideally you shouldn't do that in the XMLParser class because it is violating the Single Responsibility principle in Object Oriented programming. See more about S.O.L.I.D here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass String packageName from MainActivity to parseXML() method

Step #1: Call `putExtra()` on the `Intent` you create for the `startActivity()` call, passing in the `packageName` and some key

Step #2: In the oddly-named `XMlParser` class' `onCreate()` method, call `getIntent().getStringExtra()`, supplying the same key, to get the value

> Why this toast message didn't appear. I don't know what are the errors exactly

Because your `startActivity()` call is for an `Intent` pointing at an `XMLResult` class, not `XMlParser`.

Answer (score 0):

So how its going to work.

Just assumption `XMlParser` doesn't have any UI.

```
//We are treating XMlParser as utility class
public class XMlParser{

  private Context mContext;
  private String appPackageName;

  public XMlParser(Context context, String packageName)
  {
   this.mContext = context;
   this.appPackageName = packageName;
  }

  public void parseXML(){
    String input = appPackageName + ".xml";
    .........................
    .........................
    .........................
    String result = something;
    Toast.makeText(mContext, result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Now, `onListItemClick` just call simple class and method

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        String packageName = app.packageName;
        XMlParser xmlParser = new XMlParser(getApplicationContext(), packageName); // We are passing application context and package name as argument
        xmlParser.parseXML();
 }
```

**Note:** If your xml parsing is time consuming better to use `AsyncTask` to do this parsing stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm very new with android.

Comment: It didn't appear anything. When this onListItemClick call parseXML() method, at least this toast message should appear, right?

Comment: I'm very sorry for my English if you are hard to understand.

Comment: Please show me XMParser class as an Activity class, it has setContentView(). show on new layout.

Comment: When I click, pass string values to XMLParser class and start new activity, I mean result on new layout. Please help me.

Comment: @MaungMaung- Post your XMLParser class complete code in your question.

Comment: @user370305- I'll post now. Thank you for your concerned.

Comment: @user370305-I've posted and please take a look for me.Thank you.